# org.bouncycastle.asn1.ocsp appeared in my vs2022 code without my asking?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, bouncycastle, visual-studio-2022, intellicode

I was doing a code review / pull request merge this morning, and discovered:

"using org.bouncycastle.asn1.ocsp;"

...in a .cs page for my WebAPI.

The most recent previous addition was my adding an early return for an async Task to that file, but nothing that I can see that relates to bouncycastle. An entire solution search shows the same using statement in 2 other places added by other members of the team some months ago, but with no obvious reason for the code to be there.

Removing the using statements in all three places the code continues to work as expected.

Has anyone else seen this before? Could anyone explain what might be happening and why?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact shortcut but I'm used to press ctrl+E,ctrl+D And ctrl+S and sometime I miss a key and it add that using